# Ubuntu 15.10 Startup USB does not contain wubi and cannot boot in Windows

Tags: boot, usb, wubi

I downloaded Ubuntu 15.10 and created a startup disk with two different programs (xboot and pendrive...) The result in both cases is a startup disk that cannot start up/boot in Windows. And no .exe file also to start it from Windows. Only startup disks with older versions, e.g. 14.10 can be created in a proper way.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The startup disk you've created is supposed to start on its own. That's why it is called a startup disk. Insert it in your computer restart the computer and you'll see the computer can boot from it. You cannot use it from within Windows. If it is a USB device then make sure the computer is booting from it. The Wubi installer you're referring to is not supported anymore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply but it doesnt. And looking thru the files on that startup disk I think there are no files DOS or anything non-Ubuntu can actually read. When I boot from USB its just a blank "DOS-like" screen with a blinking cursor on top...

Comment: There isn't anything on it that is DOS or Windows like. Try again be patient and see what happens. If it still hangs after a few minutes then either the disk is not bootable or it is just wrong. Then try to  create it again. And to state tbe obvious: Linux is not Windows.

Comment: Ok I tried again with a new start up disk and then installation got stucked at first window. When I try to run Ubuntu without installation it asks me for a user name and password which obviously I dont have and never created. Another try produces now the following error message: gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image boot:

Comment: I use Ubuntu on two other computers and I am very happy with it. Instalation in the past was a piece of cake, but now it is a highly technical undertaking. Maybe easier if I take old version of Ubuntu and upgrade gradually over time?

Comment: Ok people i think I figured out the problem why start up disks of the Ubuntu downloads dont work. I read in other threads that the homepage has been compromised for some time. So I will try some time later again. Sorry for bothering.